# Fetch all Form tags from HTML from console in eclipse selenium java

Tags: eclipse, selenium

I got the HTML in console using getpagesource in selenium java .
Now i need only the tag 'Forms' in the console result.
How do i do that?

```
public class Test {

private static final String HTMLPageSourceCode = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Selenium project\\chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();


    driver.get("https://''/tandem/login/?");
    String pagesource = driver.getPageSource();
    System.out.println(pagesource);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code snippet for this :

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

//Sample Java class to fetch list of all tag with tagname forms

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String geckoDriverPath=Class1.class.getResource("/firefox/geckodriver.exe").getPath();          
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",geckoDriverPath);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.URL.com");
        List<WebElement>list =driver.findElements(By.tagName("form"));
        for(WebElement ele:list) {
            System.out.println(ele.getText());
        }       

    }
}
```

Once you get the lists you can fetch individual form element and perform action like getting text.Hope, this helps

Comment: Thank you @prateekSethi